# PL/SQL Developer settings are reset after reboot

Tags: settings, plsqldeveloper

I faced the following issue with my PL/SQL Developer. When my PC is rebooted all my preferences are reset to defaults. I guess something happens with my registry maybe (because PC is in my work office). I think there are some settings that turn off registry cleaning when PC is rebooted.
Any help or information would be appreciated.
OS: Windows 7 x64
PL/SQL Developer version: 11

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out that Developer directory was read-only. Turned it off and everything went OK.

UPD: Found out, that settings were purged after each PL/SQL Developer closing. To fix it go to `%DEVELOPER_INSTALLATION_DIR%\params.ini` and check the following variables set to existing folders: `prefpath` and `defaultprefpath`. Note that they mustn't be commented.